# Initialize custom int type in Go

Tags: types, go

In Go it is valid to create a type:

```
type Num int
```

but how can one then initialize that type? make(Num, 2) does not seem to work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Initialize the type as you would initialize the underlying type. In your example, the underlying type is an `int`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Num int

func main() {
    var m Num = 7
    n := Num(42)
    fmt.Println(m, n)
}

Output: 7 42
```

The built-in function [make](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) takes a type T, which must be a slice, map or channel type.